# use a folder in sibling container raleted to other stage

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a pipeline with two stages. in first one I build an image based on Dockerfile from "node:latest". in this stage I run "npm run build" and it create build folder.
in second stage I want to use previously built "build" folder and run it in "nginx" container. 
but I cant share folder between to stages in Gitlab-ci ce.

I use docker executor  as gitlab-runner.
**gitlab-ci-yml**

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--insecure-registry=mygitlab:5050"]

stages:
- build
- test
- release

variables:
  DEV_IMAGE: mygitlab:5050/development/registry:dashboard-dev
  RELEASE_IMAGE: mygitlab:5050/development/registry:dashboard-prod
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"

before_script:
    - docker login -u root -p my-token mygitlab:5050

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t $DEV_IMAGE . --target=dashboard-dev
    - docker push $DEV_IMAGE
    - docker run --name dashboard-dev -d $DEV_IMAGE tail -f /dev/null
    - docker cp dashboard-dev:/src/app/build /cache
    - docker stop dashboard-dev
    - docker rm dashboard-dev
release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker build -t $RELEASE_IMAGE . --target=dashboard-prod
    - docker push $RELEASE_IMAGE
  only:
    - master
```

This is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM mygitlab:5050/development/registry:dashboard-dev AS dashboard-dev

EXPOSE 3000
COPY  . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM mygitlab:5050/development/registry:nginx AS dashboard-prod 
COPY builds/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and this is my **gitlab-runner config.toml**

```
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "dash-dock"
  url = "https://mygitlab/"
  token = "my-token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
    tls_verify = false
    extra_hosts = ["mygitlabDomain:mygitlabIP"]
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/certs/client", "/builds"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy from a previous multistage container, you need to indicate so in your docker file:

```
COPY --from=dashboard-dev builds/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

See [the COPY documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) for more information.